# How do rewards for revelations work?

Tags: baking, revelation

According to the documentation a baker should receive 1/8 XTZ for making a revelation operation.  As a solo baker I have baked about 8 blocks so far and as such I would expect to have received a total of 1 XTZ for revelation rewards, however I don't appear to have received any.

I am certain I had no downtime in this period so I am curious to understand why I would not receive any revelation rewards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the baker who generates the revelation does not earn anything (it just doesn’t lose its other rewards). It is the baker who includes the revelation that receives the reward (usually, in the first block of the next cycle).

If you have a smart baker, you could delay your revelation to your fist block in the cycle.

Also, not all blocks trigger a revelation. Only every 128 blocks is a nonce generated, that will require a nonce revelation in the next cycle.

Comment: Right It depends what xtzbaker means by making a revelation. the baker who bakes a block with a nonce hash will have to send a signed revelation operation in the next cycle otherwise he will lose his rewards for the block AND the (other) baker in the next cycle that adds the signed revelation operation into his block will be rewarded 1/8 xtz extra

Answer (score 2):

according to the doc :
bakers generate and hash a random number using commitments made during cycle (n-PRESERVED_CYCLES-2), in one out of every BLOCKS_PER_COMMITMENT = 32 blocks.

As a baker have to add a nonce_hash in only one out of (BLOCKS_PER_COMMITMENT = 32) blocks.

take a look at that [block 315648](https://tzscan.io/315648)  notice the field Nonce Hash
 is filled with nceUnQLqWXyD7JA1LFDgeHmCbqoDLPs31LHU2mz7s38RSBAZ5exVZ

the revelation for this nonce is present [here](https://tzscan.io/ooNijdrgdf6vzgnftK6LFm2MoY7Agn2tU7w5v2uxWVpd1HmMdeF) the nonce is c4e2802f96467b65750e4e110824f39a5c200b69198e279d704a083980cc538c

if you look at the [next block 315649](https://tzscan.io/315649) the field Nonce hash is empty 
if we take 32 block ahead so [block 315680](https://tzscan.io/315680) we see again that there is a nonce hash

You should look at your baked block to check if you have indeed commited to a nonce hash

Comment: I would be interested though to compute manually the hash based on the revelation. I tried [blake2b](https://8gwifi.org/MessageDigest.jsp)  and [base58](https://incoherency.co.uk/base58/) encoding but I can't get the same hash

Comment: eztz.utility.b58cencode(eztz.library.sodium.crypto_generichash(32, eztz.utility.hex2buf('c4e2802f96467b65750e4e110824f39a5c200b69198e279d704a083980cc538c')), eztz.prefix.nce); Returns the correct value